AddLast adds to the head of the doubly circular linked list intead of the tail in Java
I have this homework where I need to create a doubly circular linked list for a Music Player UI. I wrote the addFirst method and it works fine but when I create the addLast method I seem to not be able to differentiate between the tail and the head. Actually I am adding to the same place in both method but somehow it should know that the one is a new head and other is a new tail. I looked over the internet and in every page they are basically doing the same thing so I am stuck.
class DoublyCircularLinkedList<T> implements IDoublyCircularLinkedList<T> {
    //instance variables
    private Node<T> current; // The current node in the list
    private Node<T> head; // The head node in the list
    private int size = 0;    // The size of the list



    //constructor
    public DoublyCircularLinkedList() {
        current = null;
        head = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    // Adds an element to the head of the list
    @Override
    public void addFirst(T data) {

        if (data instanceof Music) {
            Music musicData = (Music) data;
            File songFile = new File(musicData.getPath());

            if (!songFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Song file does not exist: " + musicData.getPath());
                return;  // Stop if the song file doesn't exist
            }
        }


        Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(data);

        if (size == 0) {
            current = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            newNode.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setPrev(newNode);
            size++;
        }
        
        else {
            Node<T> tail = head.getPrev();
            newNode.setNext(head);//setting new nodes next node to head
            head.setPrev(newNode);
            newNode.setPrev(tail);
            tail.setNext(newNode);
            head = newNode;//setting the new node as the head 
            current = newNode;
            size++;
        }
        
    }

    // Adds an element to the tail of the list
    @Override
    public void addLast(T data) {

        if (data instanceof Music) {
            Music musicData = (Music) data;
            File songFile = new File(musicData.getPath());

            if (!songFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Song file does not exist: " + musicData.getPath());
                return;  // Stop if the song file doesn't exist
            }
        }

        Node<T> newNode = new Node<>(data);
        if (size == 0) {
            current = newNode;
            head = newNode;
            newNode.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setPrev(newNode);
            size++;
        } 
        
        else {
            Node<T> tail = head.getPrev();
            newNode.setPrev(tail);
            tail.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setNext(head);
            head.setPrev(newNode);
            current = newNode;
            size++;
            
        }
        
    }}


How have you verified that addLast is not doing what you intend? Can you add the (shortest possible) code with which you arrived at a wrong result?

And while we're on the topic of "shortest possible": Should there be special handling of Music objects in a generic collection? And is that special handling necessary to show that new elements are inserted in the beginning instead of the end?

The linkedList is being used for an MP3 player UI and when I try to add a song to end with the Add to End button it just adds the song to the beginning of the list. The UI part was given to us as a part of the homework and no one had a problem with it. We should just implement this class according to the interface so the problem should be in addLast method. I can sysout things if it makes the problem clearer.

"The problem should be in the addLast method": how have you established that? You should not need any UI to prove that. Can you provide code with some System.out.println calls with which you can show the list is not building as intended?

I am sorry, your code looks correct, so we are not necessarily convinced that the wrong behaviour that you are observing is due to the code that you have posted. I know it‘s hard the first time you create a [mre]. But without one we may not be able to help you.

as I understand the posted code, it should be working as expected -- addFirst() and addLast() should do almost the same for a double circular linked list; only difference: addFirst() must change the head, addLast() not. Are you sure the problem is not in UI (e.g. not updating after head has changed) ? Have you unit tested the list (alone) ?

I just tested the posted code, I had to add my version of missing parts - it worked as expected - that is, posted code is not a [mre]  - it is not: 1) minimal  - the Music and File check¹ are probably not relevant; 2) reproducible - it is missing parts || ( ¹ somewhat strange to have a generic list checking for a specific type and the existence of some file )

I think the problem is that when you call the addLast function, you pass the current to the newNode.
I believe that when you add it to the end of the list, you should keep the current in the place it was so that the songs continue in the order they were in until you reach the last node and start over.
If you pass the current to the last node when you add it at the end, it looks like you moved to the last song and then go to the first song in the list.
In short: The way you add them to both is correct, but you shouldn't change the current when you add them at the end.
When you change the current to the newNode, it gives the impression that it becomes the first node, as it is current now, however it remains the last node in the list, as you did not change the head.
